# Background size not working in Opera Mini despite Modernizr thinking it should

Tags: opera, modernizr, opera-mini, css

I am using **Modernizr** to detect whether browsers support the CSS3 property `background-size` for a mobile site I'm building.

I'm testing the site in the **Opera Mini 6 Simulator** on [the official Opera website](http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/), and Modernizr detects that the browser supports `background-size` and adds the class 'backgroundsize' to the `<html>` element accordingly.

However when I then use the `background-size` property in my CSS it is not supported.

Here's the head:

```
<script src="modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>

body {
  background:url('background.gif') no-repeat 0 0 #FFF;
}

.backgroundsize body {
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}  

</style>
```

And the body content

```
<p>Content</p>   

<script>
if (Modernizr.backgroundsize == true) {alert("Background size is supported");}  
</script>
```

I am expecting the single background image to be stretched across the full width of the browser, instead it repeats; the page can be seen here - http://so.ajcw.com/mobile.htm

I guess one of five things has happened - does anyone know the reason and can offer a solution?

1. Modernizr does not work properly and has given a false positive
2. Opera Mini 6 incorrectly tells Modernizr it supports background-size when it doen't
3. The simulator is not an accurate emulation and the real Opera Mini does support background-size
4. I have written my code incorrectly
5. Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size` is [not supported in Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/)

Comment: That is the conclusion I'd come to, but the link is very helpful, thank you. I have solved the problem by adding conditional browser detection around the background-size function in the Modernizr script.  Not ideal but seems to do the job.

Comment: actually, it is, I even tested with javascript `var bgSize = ('backgroundSize' in document.documentElement.style);`, something else is happening

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this as a quick work around:

```
var isOperaMini = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') > -1);
if(isOperaMini) {
    var root = document.documentElement;
    root.className += " opera-mini";
}
```

It add's a class "opera-mini" to the html element. Therefore you can target Opera Mini. An example below:

```
.icon {
    background-image: url("icon-social.svg");
    background-size: 32px;
}

html.opera-mini .icon,
html.no-svg .icon {
    background-image: url("icon-social.png");
}
```

See more at: http://anthonydillon.com/blog/#sthash.VUV1hIy2.dpuf

Answer (score 1):

It seems things have changed. For my Opera Mini 7.5 on Android.

```
Modernizr.backgroundsize == true;
```

And it responds correctly to percentage values as well as to `cover` and `contain`.

Answer (score 0):

@anthony's answer doesn't work as it's not resetting / removing the background-size property for Opera Mini. The correct way to do this is:

```
.class {
  -o-background-size:cover;
  -background-size:cover;
}
x:-o-prefocus, .class {
  -o-background-size:;
  background-size:;
}
```

The *x:-o-prefocus* targets just Opera browsers.